# Foward HTTP request and capture response

Tags: spring, spring-boot

I have a spring boot application with a rest controller that will accept http requests from an external party **A**.

I want to forward this request onto another party **B**. The data from the response of **B** needs to be captured and then forward back to **A**.

My initial thoughts were to just make another request via RestTemplate, wait for the response, capture the necessary data, and then forward back to **A**.

I'm just wondering if there is potentially a slicker approach to this?

TIA

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Its fine, or just configure web proxy if you dont need to do any processing eg using Apache HTTPD or NginX

Answer (score 1):

I think the question is not completely clear. It depends on the type of tasks being performed by "A" and "B". Can you validate the input requests of "A"? So you can save invalid calls to "B". Does "A" require error responses, if there is any error in responses from "B"? In this case you can just save the error response in your data base instead  of sending error responses to "A".

If you are just sending requests and responses from "A" to "B" without any action to perform on request and response data. I guess the way you are suggesting already works faster.